# Custom Validators in Reactiv form not return true

Tags: angular, typescript

I created a method for custom validation and I can not return true value from this method. 
This is my method:

```
requiredFileType(categoryList: CategoryModel[]) {
    return function (control: FormControl) {
      const file = control.value;
      if (file) {
        const extension = file;

        for (let i = 0; i < categoryList.length; i++) {

          for (let j = 0; j < categoryList[i].productModel.length; j++) {
            for (let k = 0; k < categoryList[i].productModel[j].imageProduct.length; k++) {
              console.log(categoryList[i].productModel[j].imageProduct[k].image_path);
              if (categoryList[i].productModel[j].imageProduct[k].image_path.includes(extension)) {
                console.log(categoryList[i].productModel[j].imageProduct[k].image_path);
                return {

                  requiredFileType: null
                };
              }
            }

          }

        }
        return {
          requiredFileType: true
        };
      }

      return {
        requiredFileType: true
      };
    };
  }
```

I do not the understend, I do not have an error, my loop work good but when need return true method return null;

This is my FormControl:

```
 'image': new FormControl(image, this.requiredFileType(this.categoryList)),
```

Answer (score 1):

when your validation succeeds you should return `null` from [ValidatorFn](https://angular.io/api/forms/ValidatorFn)

> A function that receives a control and synchronously returns a map of validation errors if present, otherwise **null**.

instead of

```
return {
  requiredFileType: null
};
```

do

```
return null;
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. But my ' return {
        requiredFileType: true
      };' not work. I do not get true results.

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As you're returning an object when the validation succeeds, like:

```
return {
  requiredFileType: null
};
```

Angular isn't able to get an idea what boolean you're returning. You need to return only null when validation passes like:

```
return null;
```

returning an object is required only when validation fails as you have to specify key like:

```
return{
      requiredFileType: true
    };
```

And then requiredFileType key in errors collection can be used later.

Comment: Ok, know I understand. Thanks.